# How can I prevent the user from doing anything during a delay using a Handler?

Tags: android, android-handler

I know this question may be not clear enough . Is there a way to prevent user from clicking or doing anything on screen during delaying (3 seconds) using `Handler` .

Comment: Your question is too brief - to the point I am not sure whether the handler is generating the delay or you want to use a handler to prevent user action.  Please also provide details of what you have tried and ideally code snippets.

Comment: I need 3 seconds delay for doing something on a button . So if user clicked on any other button , it would make something wrong . So I want to prevent user from doing anything during 3 seconds .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to prevent that is disabling all the touchable events. You can combine this flags with your check events.

Code to block:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

To unblock (clear that flags):

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had better show dialog(waiting dialog...) with setCancelable(false) for that 3 seconds.

Comment: I can't using `dialog` in my app because I need  3 seconds delay for doing something on a `button` . So if user clicked on any other `button` . it would make something wrong . So I want to prevent user from doing anything during 3 seconds .

Answer (score 0):

You must use a dialog with loading, which will let the user know that something is under progress.

```
  private void showLoading(String msg) {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading);
        TextView msgtv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        msgtv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        msgtv.setText(msg);
        if (msg.isEmpty()) {
            msgtv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.alpha_transparent)));

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

        dialog.show();

        // this runnable will hide dialog after sometime if networkresponse is slow.
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                LogManager.i(TAG, "run");
                if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                    LogManager.i(TAG, "run dialog");

                    //     if (status_network_connection) {
                    if (isNetworkConnected()) {

                    } else {
                        showNetworkError();

                    }
                    hideCustomDialog();
                    //  }


                }


            }
        }, 3000);
    }
```

use below code to hide dialog

```
// hide loading dialog
public void hideCustomDialog() {
    if (dialog != null) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
    dialog = null;
}
```

create a xml file `loading.xml` which wil define the loading view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/progres"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/progress_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/inner_img_xl">

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/inner_img_m"
        android:textColor="@color/colorDividerGray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_button_s"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prevent user to do any action is through **progress dialog box**.
Android is build around this, as it help user to understand whats going on behind the scene.

you can use:

```
    progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
```

to prevent further user action at time of loading.